# Fonte personalizada no HTML dentro do IE10?

Tags: css3, internet-explorer

Ao testar no Chrome, Firefox e no Safari, todos executaram fluidamente com a fonte em meu site, porém quando testei no IE9 ele não reconheceu a fonte que importei, qual o problema?

Importei a fonte de uma pasta dentro do projeto do site:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nomeDaMinhaFonte';
    src: url("endereçoDaMinhaFonte/FRADM.TTF");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As versões 7, 8 e 9 do Internet Explorer aceitam o @font-face apenas se a font for EOT.

Você pode encontrar qualquer conversor online que esse problema é resolvido.

Você pode verificar a compatibilidade no Can I Use: [**Font Face**](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face)

Você pode converter suas fonts para EOT diretamente no [**Font Squirrel**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). 
O Safari, Firefox, Chrome e Opera aceitam fonts em TTF e OTF.

Compatibilidade entre formatos de fonte:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Browser | IE8+ |   Chrome  |   Firefox |   Safari  |
|---------|------------------------------------------|
| Formato | EOT  | TTF e OTF | TTF e OTF | TTF e OTF |       
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Para o suporte de fontes em diversos navegadores você pode fazer assim:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ‘NomeDaFont';
  src: url(‘nomedafont.eot’); /* EOT para IE */
  src: url(‘nomedafont?#iefix’) format(‘embedded-opentype’),
       url(‘nomedafont.svg#Locaweb-Icons’) format(‘svg’), /* SVG */
       url(‘nomedafont.ttf’) format(‘truetype’); /* TTF para Safari, Firefox, Chrome e Opera */
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O navegador Internet Explorer tem suporte parcial a fonte `.ttf`, leia mais em:

- [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/the-css-corner-better-web-typography-for-better-design)

Para o Internet Explorer você pode usar o formato `.eot` que é suportado desde o *Internet Explorer 8*

- [Formato EOT](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eot) da suporte para IE8+
- [Formato WOFF](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) suporte *parcial* a partir do IE8 e suporte completo a partir do IE9+
- [Formato TTF](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf) da suporte *parcial* a partir do IE9+
- [Formato SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts) não é suportado pelo Internet Explorer

Você pode converter a fonte (tome cuidado com questões de licenciamento) e adiciona-las assim para suportar em vários navegadores:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'suaFonte';
    src: url('../fonts/font1.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/font1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/font1.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/font1.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/font1.svg#font1') format('svg');
}
```