# Glyphicons do bootstrap não estão funcionando

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Alguém poderia me dizer por que glyphicons do bootstrap não estão funcionando?

Ele fica assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés de ficar assim...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

`<a href="" style="color: #ffffff;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Novidades </a>`

Todos estão desse jeito.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Fonte personalizada no HTML dentro do IE10?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51022/fonte-personalizada-no-html-dentro-do-ie10)

Comment: Você alterou o diretório `fonts` ou `css`?

Comment: @EduardoSilva 


http://i.imgur.com/TlTHY5Z.png

http://i.imgur.com/rMvkxRa.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Isso não tem nada á ver com minha pergunta.

Comment: Parece que não Leonardo, mas as glyphicons são fontes também, por isto a mensagem do meu comentário veio com *POSSIVEL*, pode ser uma duplicata como também pode não ser. Poderia fornecer um exemplo completo de como inseriu os CSSs e fontes? Talvez um link online?

Comment: Qual navegador ocorre? Todos? Firefox, Chrome, IE11?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só testei no chrome


http://i.imgur.com/TlTHY5Z.png

http://i.imgur.com/rMvkxRa.png

Comment: Então testa nos demais navegadores. **Nota:** imagens raramente ajudam a detectar o problema, forneça um exemplo "funcional", obrigado.

Comment: No internet explorer se quer aparece aquele icone quadrado.

Isso não acontece apenas com os glyphicons, mas também com os fa icons.

Comment: Após a resposta, posso presumir que o motivo do fechamento seria: *Fora do escopo > Esse problema não pode **ser reproduzido**, ou é um **erro de digitação**.*

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ok, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi, faltava os arquivos das fontes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]